# Javascript - WinRT - How share score with twitter or Facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8, windows-runtime, sharing

I make a html5/JS game on WinRT for Windows 8.
I would like to share score of a game with twitter or Facebook. Can we do this ? There is a the sharing contract, but I only know it for email. Can we use it for Facebook and Twitter ?

Thanks for your time, 
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter JavaScript API library](https://github.com/remy/twitterlib)

[A Twitter library in JavaScript](https://github.com/mynetx/codebird-js)

[Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

[Facebook WinKJS SDK](https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-winjs-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to learn the Facebook and Twitter APIs to share the score from your game.

There are two halves to the sharing contract: a share source and a share target.  You are implementing a share source, because you want to share data from your app.  As a share source, the way to share any data (whether to email or Facebook or Twitter) is to respond to the DataRequested event and build up a data package with the data you want to share.  Then that data is handed to the Win8 operating system's sharing broker, which will look for "share target" applications that accept the type of data that is being shared.  (You can share various types of data: unformatted text, formatted text, links/URIs, images, files, your own custom types...)  For example, let's say that you choose to share some unformatted text like "I just scored x on the awesome game Y!".  There are existing Twitter and Facebook apps that are share targets and could tweet/post this to your wall.

So, as a share source, all you need to worry about is packaging up the data.  The share target app will take care of the rest (and that will contain the Facebook and Twitter-specific logic).

Sample code for a share source: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84